# API PHP trade ogre error {"success":false,"error":"Invalid market"}

Tags: php

I cannot make order on tradeogre API and get error Invalid market, can you help to solve this?

I got error

> {"success":false,"error":"Invalid market"}

I've tried with, without, double quotes, swapped keys around. Nothing seems to work. Just trying to get it working in bash for now.

```php
$authBasic = base64_encode(APIKEY.":".APISECRET);
$data = array(
     'market' => 'BTC-USDT',
         'quantity  ' => '1',
          'price  ' => '1',
);
 

$json = json_encode($data);
$url = 'https://tradeogre.com/api/v1/order/buy';
$ch = curl_init($url);
 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
       "Authorization: Basic $authBasic",
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json)
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo $response;
}
curl_close($ch);
//    echo $data;

$authBasic = base64_encode(APIKEY.":".APISECRET);
$data = array(
     'market' => 'BTC-USDT',
         'quantity  ' => '1',
          'price  ' => '1',
);
 

$json = json_encode($data);
$url = 'https://tradeogre.com/api/v1/order/buy';
$ch = curl_init($url);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
       "Authorization: Basic $authBasic",
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json)
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo $response;
}
curl_close($ch);
//    echo $data;
```

here is the document https://tradeogre.com/help/api

Comment: I don't see anything terribly wrong with your code. However, you do POST as JSON, and I cannot confirm the API will process that correctly. Given the minimal documentation, the code itself might also be minimal, which would then include the error messages it gives. You could try [a more standard way to create a POST call](https://phppot.com/php/php-curl-post/).

Comment: That's an API response.. I'd say go ask the vendor why it happens. Maybe your account isn't eligible to sell in this market?

Comment: Or maybe the market code is simply not correct or is not recognised by the API? We can help you with code, but we may not always be able to comment on data which is specific to the business domain.